# add array + mousePressed

Tags: arrays, video, processing, slideshow, series

Can anyone help me add elements to this code?

Firstly, I want this to show as a series of short videos but I don't know where to add/ write the array into this sketch.

Secondly, I need a mousePressed function to tap through each video from 1 to 6 - including a jump function (if thats the right terminology) from video 6 back to video 1 repeating the series.

These videos don't play naturally from start to finish as its being manipulated by the void draw function which is why I need a mousePressed action tapping to the next video.

Here is the code, thank you for any help!

```java
import processing.video.*;

Movie mov;
int newFrame = 0;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  background(0);
  // Load and set the video to play. Setting the video 
  // in play mode is needed so at least one frame is read
  // and we can get duration, size and other information from
  // the video stream. 
  mov = new Movie(this, "video1.mp4");  

  // Pausing the video at the first frame. 
  mov.play();
  mov.jump(0);
  mov.pause();
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  image(mov, 0, 0, width, height);
  fill(255);
  text(getFrame() + " / " + (getLength() - 1), 10, 30);
  int f=ceil (map(mouseX,0,width,1,getLength()));
  setFrame(f);
}

//void keyPressed() {
//  if (key == CODED) {
//    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
//      if (0 < newFrame) newFrame--; 
//    } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
//      if (newFrame < getLength() - 1) newFrame++;
//    }
//  } 
//  setFrame(newFrame);  
//}

int getFrame() {    
  return ceil(mov.time() * 30) - 1;
}

void setFrame(int n) {
  mov.play();

  // The duration of a single frame:
  float frameDuration = 1.0 / mov.frameRate;

  // We move to the middle of the frame by adding 0.5:
  float where = (n + 0.5) * frameDuration; 

  // Taking into account border effects:
  float diff = mov.duration() - where;
  if (diff < 0) {
    where += diff - 0.25 * frameDuration;
  }

  mov.jump(where);
  mov.pause();  
}  

int getLength() {
  return int(mov.duration() * mov.frameRate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, I want this to show as a series of short videos but I don't know where to add/ write the array into this sketch.

You would use an array instead of your existing `mov` variable. Your `mov` variable holds a single movie, so you'd want to use an array to hold 6 movies instead.

Change this line:

```java
Movie mov;
```

To this:

```java
Movie[] movies = new Movie[6];
```

This creates an array that holds 6 `Movie` instances.

You would then need to fill that array.

```java
movies[0] = new Movie(this, "video1.mp4");
movies[1] = new Movie(this, "video2.mp4");
```

Or you could use a `for` loop.

> Secondly, I need a mousePressed function to tap through each video from 1 to 6 - including a jump function (if thats the right terminology) from video 6 back to video 1 repeating the series.

Then just create an `int` variable that holds the current index. Use that index wherever you're currently using the `mov` variable. Increment that index in the `mousePressed()` function, and reset it to 0 when it reaches 6.

It's hard to answer general "How do I do this?" type questions. Stack Overflow is designed more for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. So I really suggest you **try something** and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you get stuck. I've tried breaking your problem down into smaller steps for you, so focus on one of those small steps at a time. Good luck.